# Where is sxtrace.exe?

Tags: windows, manifest

I want to trace SideBySide errors for a Delphi application that fails if there exists manifest file.

Internets recommend "sxtrace.exe", which I cannot find nor on my WinXp PC nor on Win7x64, nor from where to download it.

Community, please help!

Comment: I'm half expecting an answer suggesting a completely different tool to be accepted (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133881/how-can-i-use-delphi-function-fileexists-in-embarcadero-xe5-ide/21134098#21134098)  ;-)

Comment: @David, for instance Solitaire :-) ALZ, the next time you better ask such question on SuperUser.

Comment: @ALZ I rolled back your question edit. If you change the question to ask where to find `sxstrace`, then the question and answer no longer make any sense at all.

Comment: @RBA, thanks, I am happy that i found quick response, even if I hope you'll really and sincerely be happy if question will be closed.
TLama, thanks for suggestions.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, please your opinion - should i delete question at all or leave it for history?

Comment: You cannot delete it whilst it has an accepted answer with an upvote. If mods feel so inclined they will close the question and delete it.

Comment: OK, Thanks to all, IMHO subject is consumed (next time I'll be more carefully ;))

Comment: @ALZ - FYI, nobody is happy and doesn't earn something when a question is closed.

Comment: @RBA, anyway I would like that all people around the world would be happy and also I would like a little bit more that if somebody down-vote, close attempt and so on, would specify briefly reason - this would help nubs (as me) doing it better next time ;)

Comment: @ALZ - for that exists http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the utility is `sxstrace`. You have mis-typed it as `sxtrace`. It is present in the system directory of your Windows 7 machine for sure. I suspect that it is not present on your XP machine.

Comment: Yes, 1 - mistaped only SO in question and in Win7 search :) - My mistake, now i Found it. I hope it may be useful for somebody even if will be closed.
on WinXP it really does not exists